# Upgrade a module after a pull request merged

Tags: python, pandas, git, github

I am new to Github this question may sound very silly. Recently I reported a bug of pandas in Python to their Github page. One guy opened a pull request to fix that bug. The bug was fixed and the pull request was merged.

I am not sure now how I can upgrade pandas with the new change. I tried

```
pip3 install  --upgrade pandas
```

and

```
conda update pandas
```

but the bug is still there when I run my code in Python. Really appreciate if someone can tell me how to upgrade the module properly after a pull request is merged

Comment: Probably they don't release the new version with the fix. If you want the version with the bug removed you have to manually install pandas from that commit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The versions of pandas available from conda and pip are those that are [marked as releases](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas#where-to-get-it). To get the latest code that has not been released yet, you would have to build it yourself from source in this case.

For pandas, the instructions to do this are given [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas#installation-from-sources).

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install [-U] pandas
```

installs packages from [PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/pandas/#files).

```
conda update pandas
```

installs from [Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pandas/).

The pull-request obviously is not yet included in a release. You can wait for the next release.

To install directly from Github ask `pip` to install using `git`:

```
pip install -U 'git+https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas.git#egg=pandas'
```

But please bear in mind you're required to install `git`, a compiler and a lot of development tools (`pandas` is written in C/C++ and have to be compiled).